# iOS7 View moves under status/nav bars when loadView called again

Tags: iphone, objective-c, layout, ios7

I have a View Controller that creates its view programatically through the `loadView` method. The purpose of the view is to display a data models contents. When the view loads it is aligned correctly under the status and navigation bar.

But at a later point I present another view modally to allow the user to select a different data model to populate the view. This causes the the `loadView` to get called again and re-create the required UI for the new data model. The problem is that the view's contents now appear under the status and navigation bars!

Please note that I am not using auto-layout due to having to support iOS4 :( Also if I include  the `extendedLayout` fix - it does fix the problem but only after the modal's dismiss animation completes leaving a jump down effect. My code below, thanks for any help.

```
- (void)loadView {

CGRect frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, [Constants ScreenWidth], [Constants ScreenHeight] - StatusBarHeight - ToolbarHeight);
self.view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
self.view.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
self.view.autoresizesSubviews = YES;
self.view.backgroundColor = [Constants categoriesScreenBackgroundColor];

CGRect scrollFrame = CGRectMake(0, 0, [Constants ScreenWidth], [Constants ScreenHeight] - StatusBarHeight - ToolbarHeight - ToolbarHeight);
UIScrollView *scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:scrollFrame];
scrollView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight |
        UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin |
        UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin;
[self.view addSubview:scrollView];

_toolbarViewController = [self createToolbarViewController];
[self.view addSubview:_toolbarViewController.view];
_toolbarViewController.productInfoWorkflowState = _productInfoWorkflowState;

UIView *containerView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:scrollView.frame];
containerView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

_headerViewController = [self createHeaderViewController];
[containerView addSubview:_headerViewController.view];

_menuViewController = [[ProductInfoMenuViewController alloc] initWithBatch:[self batchData]];
_menuViewController.delegate = self;
[containerView addSubview:_menuViewController.view];

CGRect categoriesFrame = _menuViewController.view.frame;
categoriesFrame.origin.y = _headerViewController.view.frame.size.height;
_menuViewController.view.frame = categoriesFrame;

CGRect viewFrame = containerView.frame;
viewFrame.size.height = _headerViewController.view.frame.size.height + _menuViewController.view.frame.size.height;
containerView.frame = viewFrame;

[scrollView addSubview:containerView];
scrollView.contentSize = containerView.frame.size;

_starViewController = [[StarViewController alloc] initForProduct:_productData With:[StarredItems new]];
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:_starViewController.view];
}
```

Screen layout after first load:

[image: Screen layout after first load]

Screen layout after second load:

[image: Screen layout after second load]

With Leo's suggested fix, the scrollView is correct BUT the toolbar at the bottom now appears incorrectly. Code I used (placed after the toolbar creation code above):

```
if (SYSTEM_VERSION_GREATER_THAN_OR_EQUAL_TO(@"7.0")) {
    self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = NO;
    scrollView.scrollIndicatorInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(64.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
    scrollView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(64.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
}
```

Results:

[image]

Comment: Please post a screenshot of what is expected and result.

Comment: set the origin of toolbar from (total view height - toolbar height).

Answer (score 14):

Add following code its work for me for same issue, may be its help you

```
/* ios 7 Change */
    if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 7)
    {
        self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeNone;
        self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = NO;
    }
```

Comment: I did this in loadView before setting up the offending view and it worked perfectly.

Answer (score 3):

Does this only happen on iOS 7?

Give this a try:

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar.translucent = NO;
```

Answer (score 2):

Try following:

```
 Toolbar.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin;
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
CGRect frame = CGRectMake(0, StatusBarHeight, [Constants ScreenWidth], [Constants ScreenHeight] - StatusBarHeight - ToolbarHeight);
self.view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
self.view.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
self.view.autoresizesSubviews = YES;
self.view.backgroundColor = [Constants categoriesScreenBackgroundColor];

CGRect scrollFrame = CGRectMake(0, StatusBarHeight, [Constants ScreenWidth], [Constants ScreenHeight] - StatusBarHeight - ToolbarHeight - ToolbarHeight);
UIScrollView *scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:scrollFrame];
scrollView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight |
        UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin |
        UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin;
[self.view addSubview:scrollView];
```

Comment: that only makes things worse I'm afraid :(

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is due to incorrect automatic set of content insets of the scrollview.

Try the following. In your `loadView`, set `self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets` to `NO` (only if `NSFoundationVersionNumber > NSFoundationVersionNumber_iOS_6_1`). Now, set the `contentInset` and `scrollIndicatorInsets` to the correct values depending on OS version:

```
scrollview.contentInset = scrollview.scrollIndicatorInsets = UIEdgeInsetMake(NSFoundationVersionNumber <= NSFoundationVersionNumber_iOS_6_1 ? 0 : 64, 0, 0, 0);
```

Comment: It kind of works but causes another issue :( I've attached a screen shot of the results in my original question.

Answer (score 0):

My problem was solved unmarking the check "Adjust Scroll View Insets" in the View Controller (using Storyboards).