# ios icarousel view's contentoffset is getting changed when view disappears for the first time

Tags: ios, icarousel

[image: before changing tabs][image: after changing tabs]whenever `view disappears` for the first time, `contentview's` center changes. I have not written a single line in `viewWillappear` or `viewWillDisappear` or `viewDidAppear` or `viewDidDisappear`.
Please help.. Thanks in advance...

Comment: You might want to add some more information: are you building your viewController with Interface Builder,is this happening in iOS7 only, do you show any navigation bars (and if so: are they translucent or solid)...

Comment: For example: does [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19308325/653513) match your symptoms?

Comment: actually i am using a tabBarController and when i change the selected tab of the tabBar controller, icarousel view's vertical center changes.

Comment: You might want to add this information together with some screenshots to the question - more chances of getting a good answer this way since it will be easier for others to understand your problem.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is not the problem of icarousel view but it seems you are using  UINavigationController in a wrong way because your view is shifting by 44 pixel that must be a problem of Navigation Bar not icarousel.

Comment: thanx.. it actually turned out to be problem of navigation bar.. now i am making seperate navigation controller for all the tabbBarViewControllers... It solved my problem..

Answer (score 0):

It seems like a problem due to the new iOS 7 and it's impact on UIScrolViews.

Have you tried setting `self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = NO` ?

But I would strongly suggest, if your min SDK is iOS6, use UICollectionView for your coverflow. Here is even a project on github for UICollectionView [Coverflow](https://github.com/schwa/Coverflow)